# ASP.NET tags don't expand in OnClientClick

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have the following two buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnVote" runat="server" Text="Vote!" PostBackUrl="<%$RouteUrl:id=2, routename=Results%>"/><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnResults" runat="server" Text="Results ->" OnClientClick="location.href='<%$RouteUrl:id=2, routename=Results%>'"/>
```

The first `<%$ %>` expands as intended, while the second (identical!) one gets used as typed ( = not expanded). I am very new to `ASP.NET`, coming from `PHP`, and this is from my learning/test site.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET expression syntax (`<%$ ... %>`) can only be used to directly assign values to properties of server controls.  I think the problem you're having is that the expression syntax is embedded within a string, and not directly bound to the "OnClientClick" attribute.

Trying changing your second button to

```
<asp:Button ID="btnResults" runat="server" Text="Results ->" OnClientClick="<%$RouteUrl:id=2, routename=Results%>" />
```

If that works, you may need to modify your expression to return that extra text you need.  Or, create another route that returns said info (the current value wrapped in the "location.href" attribute).

You can find more information about these expressions here: [ASP.NET Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx).

Comment: The modified button works, but now of course the button doesn't work. How would I "modify your expression to return that extra text you need"?

Comment: @baruch Aha!  That's a good question.  I'm not super familiar with what you're doing with this: `<%$RouteUrl:id=2, routename=Results%>`.  BUT, could you make another routename (we'll call it "ResultsLink") and have that route return the entire string you were trying to build?  So, "*location.href='WhatEverTextYourRouteReturns.com'*"

Comment: No, I can't. `RouteUrl` is supplied by `asp.net`. It builds a pretty URL based on the parameters it is given. Anyway, I just moved the whole thing to the codebehind.

Comment: @baruch Well that stinks.  Glad I could (try) to help though =)